# Vetur Cannot Find Module From @ when in Parent Folder

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vetur

### Overview

I'm building a front end project using Vue, Vetur, and Typescript. When I create imports in files such as App.vue, my `@` alias for the `src` folder works perfectly if I open the folder `my_project` which contains the package.json and tsconfig.json in VsCode.

### Problem

However, if I open the parent folder of `my_project`, then Vetur complains with a red squiggle that the module cannot be found. Relative imports still work perfectly. I suspect that this is an issue with the paths variable in my tsconfig.json. I have tried adding `./my_project/src/*`, but this doesn't make any difference. Any help would be appreciated.

### Files

App.vue import:

```
import { Testing } from '@/Testing
```

tsconfig.json paths:

```
"paths": {
   "@/*": ["./src/*", "./my_project/src/*"]
}
```